# How to find the Stack Overflow URL of an user?

Tags: support, users

Without using a web search, is there a way to find the URL or an user knowing only the nickname?
The alternative could be to search the user's main page URL, or is there a page that list all users URLs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nicknames are not unique; you'd have to search on a [site's Users page (on the `all` tab)](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all) to match nicknames to user ids.

In other words, there is no guarantee I am the only one using the nickname "Martijn Pieters" on Stack Overflow, so there is no one-to-one mapping to a user URL for that nickname.

Comment: It's fairly safe to say that if they don't answer a question in 2 seconds - it's not you though ;)